# Google_Http_MediaFileUpload constructor must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to upload large files in newly created folder in google drive via php . 
but when I am not using

```
   $client->setDefer(true);
```

Then I am getting this error:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 2 passed to Google_Http_MediaFileUpload::__construct() must implement interface Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface, instance of Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile given, called in /var/www/html/google_drive2/gdrive_upload.php on line 158 and defined in /var/www/html/google_drive2/src/Google/Http/MediaFileUpload.php on line 78

And when I use

```
    $client->setDefer(true);
```

Then i get this:

> Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message 'Not Found' in /var/www/html/google_drive2/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118
>   ( ! ) Google_Service_Exception: Not Found in /var/www/html/google_drive2/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118

Tried everything but fails. please tell what I am doing wrong.

Here is my complete code of gdrive_upload.php

https://pastebin.com/x96CZg3U

Comment: Please post your code see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I allready posted in pastebin https://pastebin.com/x96CZg3U

Comment: Stack doesnt do paste bin you must supply a small sample that we can use to test not your full code.   Edit your question and include enough code to show the problem.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The error:

Google_Service_Exception: Not Found in /path/to/src/Google/Http/REST.php on line 118

occurs when you are passing an invalid reference to the Google API and the API cannot find the resource you are requesting.

For example, when adding a file to Google Drive, this will show when an invalid Google Drive Id is passed.
When adding an event to Google Calendar, this will show when an invalid Google Calendar Id is passed.
Etc.

In your case, the folder is probably not fully set up yet. So you are using a valid Id, but Google has not fully created the folder. Using $client->setDefer(true) probably allows Google enough time to fully set up the folder, which allows your folder Id to validate.

Disclaimer: This error quite possibly appears for other circumstances as well.